# Custom std::any implementation: template copy and move constructors overloading problem

Tags: c++

I've written my own std::any implementation that has configurable small value optimization (STL has no configuration for this and default values are very small, e. g. in GCC it's just one pointer size).

```
#pragma once
 
#include <cstddef>
#include <cstring>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <new>
#include <utility>
 
template<std::size_t STORAGE_SIZE> class Any {
    typedef void (*CopyFunc)(void *dst, const void *src);
    typedef void (*MoveFunc)(void *dst, void *src);
    typedef void(*DestroyFunc)(void *val);
    
    struct Operations {
        const std::type_info &typeInfo;
        std::size_t size;
        std::size_t align;
        CopyFunc copy;
        MoveFunc move;
        DestroyFunc destroy;
    };
    
    template<typename T> static inline constexpr Operations OPERATIONS = {
            .typeInfo = typeid(T),
            .size = ([]() {
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, void>) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return sizeof(T);
                }
            })(),
            .align = ([]() {
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, void>) {
                    return 0;
                } else {
                    return alignof(T);
                }
            })(),
            .copy = ([]() {
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, void> || std::is_trivially_copy_constructible_v<T>) {
                    return nullptr;
                } else {
                    return static_cast<CopyFunc>([](void *dst, const void *src) {
                        new (dst) T(*reinterpret_cast<const T*>(src));
                    });
                }
            })(),
            .move = ([]() {
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, void> || std::is_trivially_move_constructible_v<T>) {
                    return nullptr;
                } else {
                    return static_cast<MoveFunc>([](void *dst, void *src) {
                        new (dst) T(std::move(*reinterpret_cast<T*>(src)));
                    });
                }
            })(),
            .destroy = ([]() {
                if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T, void> || std::is_trivially_destructible_v<T>) {
                    return nullptr;
                } else {
                    return static_cast<DestroyFunc>([](void *arg) {
                        reinterpret_cast<T*>(arg)->~T();
                    });
                }
            })()
    };
    
    std::size_t m_storage[(STORAGE_SIZE + sizeof(std::size_t) - 1) / sizeof(std::size_t)];
    void *m_heapStorage = nullptr;
    const Operations *m_operations = &OPERATIONS<void>;
 
public:
    Any() = default;
    
    template<typename T> Any(const T &value) {
        if constexpr (sizeof(T) > sizeof(m_storage) || alignof(T) > alignof(std::size_t)) {
            m_heapStorage = new T(value);
        } else {
            new (m_storage) T(value);
        }
        m_operations = &OPERATIONS<T>;
    }
    
    template<typename T> Any(T &&value) noexcept {
        if constexpr (sizeof(T) > sizeof(m_storage) || alignof(T) > alignof(std::size_t)) {
            m_heapStorage = new T(std::move(value));
        } else {
            new (m_storage) T(std::move(value));
        }
        m_operations = &OPERATIONS<T>;
    }
    
    template<std::size_t N> Any(const Any<N> &value) {
        if (value.m_heapStorage || value.m_operations->size > sizeof(m_storage)) {
            m_heapStorage = new (std::align_val_t(value.m_operations->align)) char[value.m_operations->size];
            if (value.m_operations) {
                value.m_operations->copy(m_heapStorage, value.m_heapStorage ? value.m_heapStorage : value.m_storage);
            } else {
                std::memcpy(
                        m_heapStorage,
                        value.m_heapStorage ? value.m_heapStorage : value.m_storage,
                        value.m_operations->size
                );
            }
        } else {
            if (value.m_operations->copy) {
                value.m_operations->copy(m_storage, value.m_storage);
            } else {
                std::memcpy(m_storage, value.m_storage, value.m_operations->size);
            }
        }
        m_operations = value.m_operations;
    }
    
    template<std::size_t N> Any(Any<N> &&value) noexcept {
        m_operations = value.m_operations;
        if (value.m_heapStorage) {
            m_heapStorage = value.m_heapStorage;
            value.m_heapStorage = nullptr;
            value.m_operations = &OPERATIONS<void>;
        } else {
            if (value.m_operations->size > STORAGE_SIZE) {
                m_heapStorage = new (std::align_val_t(value.m_operations->align)) char[value.m_operations->size];
            }
            if (m_operations->move) {
                m_operations->move(m_heapStorage ? m_heapStorage : m_storage, value.m_storage);
            } else {
                std::memcpy(m_heapStorage ? m_heapStorage : m_storage, value.m_storage, value.m_operations->size);
            }
        }
    }
    
    ~Any() {
        if (m_operations->destroy) {
            m_operations->destroy(m_heapStorage ? m_heapStorage : m_storage);
        }
        if (m_heapStorage) {
            delete static_cast<char*>(m_heapStorage);
        }
    }
    
    [[nodiscard]] const std::type_info &type() const {
        return m_operations->typeInfo;
    }
    
    [[nodiscard]] std::size_t size() const {
        return m_operations->size;
    }
    
    [[nodiscard]] std::size_t align() const {
        return m_operations->align;
    }
    
    [[nodiscard]] bool isHeapAllocated() const {
        return m_heapStorage != nullptr;
    }
    
    template<typename T> [[nodiscard]] const T *get() const {
        if (m_operations->typeInfo == typeid(T)) {
            return reinterpret_cast<const T*>(m_heapStorage ? m_heapStorage : m_storage);
        } else {
            return nullptr;
        }
    }
    
    template<typename T> [[nodiscard]] T *get() {
        if (m_operations->typeInfo == typeid(T)) {
            return reinterpret_cast<T*>(m_heapStorage ? m_heapStorage : m_storage);
        } else {
            return nullptr;
        }
    }
    
    void clear() {
        if (m_operations->destroy) {
            m_operations->destroy(m_heapStorage ? m_heapStorage : m_storage);
        }
        if (m_heapStorage) {
            delete static_cast<char*>(m_heapStorage);
            m_heapStorage = nullptr;
        }
        m_operations = &OPERATIONS<void>;
    }
    
    template<typename T, typename... Args> void emplace(Args &&...args) {
        clear();
        if constexpr (sizeof(T) > sizeof(m_storage) || alignof(T) > alignof(std::size_t)) {
            m_heapStorage = new T(std::forward<Args...>(args)...);
        } else {
            new (m_storage) T(std::forward<Args...>(args)...);
        }
        m_operations = &OPERATIONS<T>;
    }
    
    template<std::size_t N> Any<STORAGE_SIZE> &operator=(const Any<N> &value) {
        clear();
        if (value.m_heapStorage || value.m_operations->size > sizeof(m_storage)) {
            m_heapStorage = new (std::align_val_t(value.m_operations->align)) char[value.m_operations->size];
            if (value.m_operations) {
                value.m_operations->copy(m_heapStorage, value.m_heapStorage ? value.m_heapStorage : value.m_storage);
            } else {
                std::memcpy(
                        m_heapStorage,
                        value.m_heapStorage ? value.m_heapStorage : value.m_storage,
                        value.m_operations->size
                );
            }
        } else {
            if (value.m_operations->copy) {
                value.m_operations->copy(m_storage, value.m_storage);
            } else {
                std::memcpy(m_storage, value.m_storage, value.m_operations->size);
            }
        }
        m_operations = value.m_operations;
        return *this;
    }
    
    template<std::size_t N> Any<STORAGE_SIZE> &operator=(Any<N> &&value) noexcept {
        clear();
        m_operations = value.m_operations;
        if (value.m_heapStorage) {
            m_heapStorage = value.m_heapStorage;
            value.m_heapStorage = nullptr;
            value.m_operations = &OPERATIONS<void>;
        } else {
            if (value.m_operations->size > STORAGE_SIZE) {
                m_heapStorage = new (std::align_val_t(value.m_operations->align)) char[value.m_operations->size];
            }
            if (m_operations->move) {
                m_operations->move(m_heapStorage ? m_heapStorage : m_storage, value.m_storage);
            } else {
                std::memcpy(m_heapStorage ? m_heapStorage : m_storage, value.m_storage, value.m_operations->size);
            }
        }
        return *this;
    }
    
    template<typename T> Any &operator=(T &&value) noexcept {
        using TT = typename std::decay<T>::type;
        emplace<TT>(std::forward<T>(value));
        return *this;
    }
};
```

But I have problem with some constructors:

```
int x = 10;
Any<64> v0 = x; // Error

Any<64> v1 = 10; // Works
Any<128> v2 = v1; // Error
```

In both error cases compiler picks `template<typename T> Any(T &&value)` instead of `template<typename T> Any(const T &value)` for the first case and `template<std::size_t N> Any(const Any<N> &value)` for the second.

How constructors overloading can be fixed?

P. S.: There is the same problem for an assignment operator when we pass `Any` instead of some value (for value everything works fine).

Comment: `Any<64> v0 = x; // Error` -> `template<typename T> Any(T &&value) noexcept` is not a rvalue reference parameter but a [Forwarding reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references) parameter and with the reference collapsing rules is an exact match for `int`.

Comment: How can I declare template constructor which accepts rvalue reference as usual move constructor and nothing else?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/46214158/5494370

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that `template<typename T> Any(T &&value)` is a forwarding/universal reference and can accept anything. In certain situations it might prefer this constructor over any kind of constructor from `Any`. So I'd recommend conditioning it so it won't be an `Any`. Also, since it accepts any input you can unify it with the `const T&` constructor into a single one - just use `std::forward`.

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!is_Any_v<std::remove_reference_t<std::remove_const_t<T> > >, int> = 0> 
Any(T &&value) noexcept {
    if constexpr (sizeof(T) > sizeof(m_storage) || alignof(T) > alignof(std::size_t)) {
        m_heapStorage = new T(std::forward<T>(value));
        } else {
            new (m_storage) T(std::forward<T>(value));
        }
        m_operations = &OPERATIONS<T>;
}
```

whereas `is_Any` is defined above the class definition as:

```
template<std::size_t STORAGE_SIZE> class Any;

template<typename T>
struct is_Any : std::false_type {};

template<std::size_t STORAGE_SIZE>
struct is_Any<Any<STORAGE_SIZE>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T>
constexpr bool is_Any_v = is_Any<T>::value;
```

Comment: That will give you an error "cannot allocate reference type '...' with new" because `T` is still a reference type.

Comment: @Nelfeal welp, he'll need to apply all the remove const/reference to new too. The code has a couple of other bugs as well, so I couldn't properly verify everything. Only the resolution of constructor as per question.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply `enable_if` non-references:

```
template<typename T, std::enable_if_t<!std::is_reference_v<T>, bool> = true>
Any(T &&value) noexcept {
// ...
```

Note that you will also need to move `Operations` out of the class.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/89PG1eco6)