# "Templated rvalue-reference" instead of universal reference as parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, forwarding-reference

I have a class object that takes universal parameters which are constrained to a certain concept. Now I want to forward this parameter (which type is still unknown) to the overload of `construct` that fits this reference type: Select either rvalue-ref overload or const ref overload based on the forwarded parameter. How can I achieve that?

The problem is that as soon as I put double ampersand the "templated rvalue ref" becomes an universal reference and I can't see a way to circumvent that. The following example shows, that in both cases the "greedy" universal ref overload is picked, even though I would like for the first instantiation to go with const ref.

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIMwBspK4AMngMmAByPgBGmMQSAMykAA6oCoRODB7evv5BaRmOAmER0SxxCVzJdpgOWUIETMQEOT5%2BgbaY9sUMjc0EpVGx8Um2TS1teZ0KE4PhwxWj1QCUtqhexMjsHOaJ4cjeWADUJoluaAzbKQQKZ9gmGgCCewdHmKfnyLP4qPePLzM%2Byu70%2Bbi8jlohAAnv9ngCCJgWCkDIiwQRoSlGKxMAA6fHHJ7EYB3RIPZ6zYheBzHKheK69AEmADsVmexw5x0RyNRHzObh%2BIBA4QAbqhRDF6PyiST8bj7sc3DE4U9ObT6fUBBAleYArraQwVqdWQC1WrLpTqQQIIKQPxiAB3Zrofk6snUQ0rM5s1WclkAESZ7M53JRTER/IxWOYbEVyrJps5TAhqGOFoIVIcEHTcd1RpZPrNnJSxHCBCoEHMZgA8iL4rRUEx0LSSGmBLMALTETBUNNiejoMBgEwAVjcDCrXsShb9zMD8ODHNDvPRmOxsbd5N9HOTRDbDEtWZ1gTzxpnRZLZYrVdr9cbzftx2IIrEXkwXZ7fdoA6Ho/Hk%2B9RMOQDJk50AhcnkPAh1QZEhQPPY5d1TVAsWIcMSAgFZMKAs8cLVS9BGvMwzAAMQ1IhiC/H9hzHCdiKnBCQPhMDpyDJ4y2OFgmHCbDmIQulYMo/hUC4cCXkXGDNQYTjoQE0xWWE0SWP48ishkuSzALOSKILEDlNA/0ODWWhOBHXg/A4LRSFQTg3GsaxjgUDYtj5IEeFIAhNCMtYAGsQEkAAOXEAo0SRmRHZlmQCDREmZapJBHfROEkcyvOszheAUEANA8ry1jgWAYEQFBUGROh4nISg0DK%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%2BRxHLgIoaCCCvdKHA845UDtfXyIB/64i4L/MwkhiKJC/gEMw1sgiP0SKbHOGUr7eSjmYHBq88GQIIXWYaWR/JAA%3D%3D)

```
#include <concepts>
#include <cstdio>
#include <utility>

template <typename... Args>
struct function
{
    template <std::invocable<Args...> Cb>
    function(Cb&& fn) {
        construct(std::forward<Cb>(fn));
    }

    template<typename Cb>
    auto construct(const Cb&) {
        printf("Overload for const-ref called!\n");
    }

    template <typename Cb>
    auto construct(Cb&&) {
        printf("Overload for rvalue-ref called!\n");
    }
};

struct functor
{
    auto operator()()
    {
        printf("Functor called!\n");
    }
};

int main()
{
    functor foo1;

    function myfunc{foo1};
    function myfunc2{functor{}};
}
```

Outputs:

```
Overload for rvalue-ref called!
Overload for rvalue-ref called!
```

**Update**:

As the above case is probably already too contrived to really showcase what I'm trying, you can find a more elaborate example [here](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGISRqkrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBIA7KQADqgKhE4MHt6%2B/oGp6Y4CoeFRLLHxXEl2mA6ZQgRMxATZPn4Btpj2RQwNTQQlkTFxibaNza25HQrjA2FD5SNVAJS2qF7EyOwc5gDMYcjeWADUJrtuaAxbyQQKZ9gmGgCCewdHmKfnyDP4qPePLzM%2Byu70%2BbjYLBIAE8APrETAKdabTD/Z4AgiYFjJAwYsEEKHJRisD4AMQYpGO%2BMJzDYxwAShSqUS2AA6NnHJ7EYB3XYPZ6Xa4EY5hABuqFE0XocM%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%2BTSsDUQlHdUL2BQEMwwECMo1QnMWGPOjGuyvKBOOeEwgxP9SJhZqCB1Ez7ggVKLOIFlwnKmFUGibRanm853N5XTF1iu94pwmysuG7LonhJhuJK66nRdD4DO9RVU3TbrM16mM4wGuCnsDUbdjlCbBDiZIZrmhbUAkoSlpW291swTbtt2hwdUO7AIHAz7jpi28YXOi7HqBwNbswe6yeIhjAZIzAyOICjSJpum7KDByhzxSdiWObHAa8xxkHpfy1V4iBIui7s4szaTuXMAA2JWGyabk6qukbGfI44CZls7M1E8D%2BGIcqmnQHUZyWtWFGWWTbIa9mXiGylS25nU1QlKViBXeWFBNe5jjcaJA/hABHLw8HhN0IDAMBwM9NggJ5Nxg4pE6e3OVd1zZGyHl5TcXYzzIIGDpWlfYilgLSu8H2r1bH0yhjC4a5MQCDeuicypGSAIxjHfqxq8CoXCZkwVQod18DlThC1vC1eEqDiRgthhEUdTLsxla3%2B4Nfp0rPtm76s1QjbcefD7UDTagGGWS798DBjji6Fqm5dxq0FDI%2B8J%2B6Mz%2BU%2B%2B796IFkBk7UBLsEJIRDEFLCokrY7y3qrJsOEAC0gc6QEU1sRUiOtlKcR4lqaghNLIUmNiQM2xALbnCtkdG2dtc5sxARzQMXNyzDmcrzWkZdeSA0gagYMX8MwnxhGfDMQcQ5b3YnvIBgY8Hiy1I%2BcGU0oaM1mi6fabg5FcVQLxe8S0tEELAhfEA8JD7IBFIvPR5xuH52wIA1uQY8GBXUrQGEijMCTUhtDdROonGMCCq4/aOM/FqTEEYl8JjMRX3TBYzAVArGpxDjwguNNkwZ0so%2BEJASYQhUMoqT%2BXUf7CP6hSJWykq5URrjCexyYwEu1YU5NwLkPg2N4YhfhZjj6/TPpvbeispGYIfmLbRuj3GeOmqomG5wDE6L4voji8jwmKlMdE2asT4kaNaSkh2jUskuLcWNJRXjJk%2BOmSpfx%2Bygk3wChcsJ5xwIrLTGsyxmykm2JqaVdJd5MnnNCa43J70QCdKKb9Eppwt7lJ7neD5j8mHOwamIzulk66VNWjCGmfkvkHNBscAqRVMw0xmbooURKFFjTxbQYqOzHG/OySS2l%2Bz8qFUpQSh2dM2VMUmimJgYRsJ5kHo4wmy5zjaT5byFMUITqNwAKxWGlTKPlfpjhQ0mlQCA5gzAAAkujXmOAAdRILQdAccTDSrcAwDVl0%2B5yUBiwSVMUxXFgLBwVYtBODSt4H4DgWhSCoE4G4aw1h5RIi2OC3YPBSAEE0C61Y3F/AAA4WTxrMNKjQitpVmASJILg0qpC7GkG6jgkhPXRt9ZwXgCgQCBCjd6l1pA4CwBgIgDqWI6BxHIJQNArb6DxGAFwMwZhSBYBFIeTAAA1PAqMADy1JOARpoLQKalaIDRFLdEMITQoRzt4F2tgggp0MG/KWrALBDDAHELWodUc9p4DTJWy949aiIW2D6zxhafW0DwLdTdHgsClszHgAa3A61UAMNyCd07Z3AZkIIEQYh2BSBg/IJQahS26C4PoM9KBA2WH0F%2BytkBVghh6PelBeqrzHBQVOt0KCUE/AEsAAqOGLBmB9TUOozgICuEmH4DDIR5hlAqHoAoGQBA8eE2kUTDBBiCaWJ0bo9RZjiYw%2BxnofRmgyeGJUMY/RlM6Y0wJrTEhViIg2FsYz%2Bh3UlsvX6jgxxVDxsVigxWkhkLIBFv2lkZhda4EIL3PYXBli8BrVoO%2BpAEBUywPEbClmi28AGtmlkuxFYJASFwXYGgNCSEkPGyQuxSBep9bZitVbI3RtWA25t6wCB7gIB2iAXbkhtuIBEYknAHNOZc25jzZgvO8EwPgW8Ek9D8Fg6IcQiHRvIZUOoS96HSDlXUskbdrqrMFdLbZqdiFavHFQCPDrznXPAHc8cTz3nS7xiaz2sNgXgvldjSAVNsXi2kAGtKxNitdgDscwATh%2B9K3N0qEhpvWzZ8tthSshZjaQONuaWRVEkD9/NCQU25fjdKxWitYu7Gs0V8HUOwuFrMLj3gxWyu1rC2mYg6RnCSCAA).

Comment: `auto construct(const Cb&)` -> `auto construct(Cb&)`?

Comment: `auto construct(Cb&&) requires(std::is_rvalue_reference_v<Cb&&>)` ??

Comment: @NathanOliver: Then `function{std::as_const(foo1)}` would select wrong overload ;-)

Comment: @n.m. What do I need the && in the requires clause for? To not collapse references?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46214158/817643

Comment: `Cb` by itself is not a reference type.

Comment: Why not simply an if constexpr inside the function with forwarding reference parameter, which checks for an lvalue reference?

Comment: @davidhigh I have done that in my elaborate example (see update section of question)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The main answer is that you should try not to do that since there is usually no good reason to perform this kind of overload resolution. When you have a *concrete* type, it makes sense to have an overload that takes an lvalue reference and an overload that takes an rvalue reference, because only the latter has license to plunder the resources from its argument. But a function template that says "I accept anything, but it has to be expiring" usually cannot do anything useful with the information that its argument is expiring, other than to eventually forward it to an overload that takes a concrete type.

However, it is possible. One way is:

```
template <typename Cb>
auto construct(Cb&&) requires(!std::is_reference_v<Cb>) {
    printf("Overload for rvalue-ref called!\n");
}
```

This uses the fact that, if the argument to a forwarding reference is an lvalue, the template argument is deduced as an lvalue reference, but if the argument is an rvalue, the template argument is deduced as the referenced type (i.e. a non-reference).

Comment: In 3+ years of coding C++ I've also never stumbled accross such a case, but in this case it  would make sense imho because the parameter is forwarded to allocator construct() through a type erased function pointer, and the new object should be move or copy constructed. What do you mean by "non-reference" anyhow? Just lvalue?

Comment: @glades It is deduced as just Cb in this case. As a result, you can also write `std::is_rvalue_reference_v<Cb&&>`. It seems counterintuitive, but the lvalue version (Cb&) && collapses to Cb& and fails this test.

Comment: @sigma perfect thank you. That seems easier to argue about than std::is_reference, and should probably be included in the answer.

Comment: @glades If you post another question with code that shows your use case, I can probably explain to you why you don't need to have a generic rvalue-specific overload.

Comment: @BrianBi No need to create a new topic, I have attached a note to a more elaborate example in the original question :) Yes I'm happy for feedback.

Comment: @glades See [simplified version of your example](https://godbolt.org/z/Mo4ra9od7).

Comment: @BrianBi Thanks, I know that works for the callstack originating from the constructor. But... i didn't show the whole truth again it seems xD. The problem is that those functions are type-erased because they also account for moving/copying functors from other function types that are type-erased (e.g. operator=()), hence I can not put the allocator in context where Cb is known :/

Comment: @glades I'm not seeing the problem here. The copy-assignment operator for a type-erased function object should copy the functor from the RHS. The move-assignment operator for a type-erased function object should move the functor from the RHS. Whether the callback was originally provided as an lvalue or rvalue during construction does not need to be remembered.

Comment: @BrianBi Yes, but for allocator.new_object() to work correctly the allocator must specialize on the type of the functor which is only known at the beginning (i.e. constructor's callstack). After that the type must be recovered either by virtual functions or by templated functions that "remember" context and type so to speak. I could make individual functions for the ctor's callstack and for operator=() but that would probably go against DRY