# Why does this overload resolution select the signature with the rvalue reference?

Tags: c++, rvalue-reference

The following program uses the `append_list` function with the rvalue reference signature, not the const reference one. Why?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <iterator>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

class foo {
public:
    std::vector<int> bar{1};
};

template<typename T, typename U>
static void append_list(T &t, const U &u) {
    t.insert(t.end(), u.begin(), u.end());
}

template<typename T, typename U>
static void append_list(T &t, U &&u) {
    printf("move\n");
    std::move(u.begin(), u.end(), std::back_inserter(t));
}

int main() {
    auto shmoo = std::make_shared<foo>();
    std::vector<int> baz{2};
    append_list(baz, shmoo->bar);
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/jdbEd1

AFAICS `shmoo->bar` should be an lvalue reference to the bar field of the `shmoo` object. I don't see a "conversion sequence" here to make an rvalue reference out of it, but I admit there's a lot going on here I don't understand.

Comment: `U&&` is a forwarding reference here, not a rvalue reference.

Comment: Related to [forwarding-reference-and-r-value-reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996187/c-forwarding-reference-and-r-value-reference)

Comment: OK, thanks. I'll check in to that.

Comment: `U` is `std::vector<int> &`

Comment: , thus `U &&` is also `std::vector<int> &` (because of the so-called *reference collapsing rules*), which this overload the better match than that other one, because that one has the extra `const`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example code, `U` is a forwarding reference and not an RValue reference:

```cpp
template<typename T, typename U>
static void append_list(T &t, U &&u) {
//                            ^~~~~
```

Forwarding references behave differently than the usual template deduced types in that `U` will become the **exact** type of its input, matching both the CV-qualifiers and value category.

- For PR values of type `T`, this produces `U = T`
- For X-values of type `T`, this produces `U = T&&`
- For L-values of type `T`, this produces `U = T&`

This differs from normal template matching where a deduced type from `const U&` would determine `U = T`.

When presented as an *overload set* with a function template that deduces its arguments via template matching, forwarding references will effectively be "greedy" -- since in most cases it will be an **unambiguously better match** for overload resolution.

---

With your example code:

```cpp
int main() {
    auto shmoo = std::make_shared<foo>();
    std::vector<int> baz{2};
    append_list(baz, shmoo->bar);
}
```

`schmoo->bar` is passing a non-`const` lvalue reference of `std::vector<int>` into `append_list`.

During overload resolution, the compiler will always resolve the function with the most exact match (i.e. requires least number of conversions required). In the above overload, `std::vector<int>&` *could* be matched to `const U&` = `const std::vector<T>&` -- but this requires adding `const`, compared to matching `U&& =` std::vector&` which is an exact match.

As a result, the forward-reference overload is called.

Comment: Excuse my nitpicking, but expressions can't have reference types. The ref-ness of the deduced template argument is determined from the *value category* of the expression.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I appreciate the nitpick -- it's much clearer to explain this specifically in terms of value categories.