# Why argument in std::move looks like (_Ty&& _Arg)?

Tags: c++, templates, move, value-categories

Why argument in `std::move` looks like `(_Ty&& _Arg)`? Why we don't need to write overloads for `(_Ty& _Arg)`

Why we don't get compilation error, when move l-value reference?

Comment: its a universal / forwarding reference.

Comment: somewhat related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3582001/what-are-the-main-purposes-of-stdforward-and-which-problems-does-it-solve

Comment: Another relevant post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996187/c-forwarding-reference-and-r-value-reference.