# Why does the + operator default to rvalue overload if using auto?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

struct Obj{ Obj(){} };
struct Obj2{ Obj2(){} };

// option 1
Obj operator+(Obj const& x0, Obj const& x1) { printf("%s\n", "+(const&, const&)"); return Obj{}; }
Obj operator+(Obj const& x0, Obj&& x1) { printf("%s\n", "+(const&, &&)"); return Obj{}; }
Obj operator+(Obj&& x0, Obj const& x1) { printf("%s\n", "+(&&, const&)"); return Obj{}; }
Obj operator+(Obj&& x0, Obj&& x1) { printf("%s\n", "+(&&, &&)"); return Obj{}; }

//option 2
// Obj2 operator+(auto const& x0, auto const& x1) { printf("%s\n", "+(const&, const&)"); return Obj2{}; }
// Obj2 operator+(auto const& x0, auto&& x1) { printf("%s\n", "+(const&, &&)"); return Obj2{}; }
// Obj2 operator+(auto&& x0, auto const& x1) { printf("%s\n", "+(&&, const&)"); return Obj2{}; }
// Obj2 operator+(auto&& x0, auto&& x1) { printf("%s\n", "+(&&, &&)"); return Obj2{}; }

int main()
{
    Obj x0;
    Obj x1{ x0 };
    auto x2 = x0 + x1;
}
```

If I choose option 1, I get the expected call of (const&, const&) since x0 and x1 are clearly lvalues. BUT, if I go for option 2, it calls the (&&, &&) overload and thinks that x0 and x1 are rvalues?! Why is this happening? Serious question. Shouldn't it go for the more constrained version anyway and ignore option 2? Even so, should it even matter what option I go for when x0 and x1 should ALWAYS be lvalues?

Comment: Unrelated: You don't need to write default ctor for `Obj` and `Obj2` as the compiler will automatically generate them.

Comment: @user12002570 yeah, ik. Lots of edits, forgot to remove them. They were printing something at some point :) They're not really that important for the question itself.

Comment: This is because in option 2, the overloaded operators are actually "function templates"(aka abbreviated functions) and behave like you have `template<typename T> operator+( T&&, T&&)` which has forwarding references and they are the best match here.

Comment: *"thinks that x0 and x1 are rvalues?..."* It does not think that. Its just that the parameters are forwarding references.

Comment: @user12002570 yeah, but option 2 chooses x0 and x1 as rvalues when it also has a definition for lvalues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> BUT, if I go for option 2, it calls the (&&, &&) overload and thinks that x0 and x1 are rvalues?! Why is this happening?

This is because in option 2, the overloaded operators are **actually "templated"**(aka [abbreviated function templates](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template#Abbreviated_function_template)) and behave like you have `template<typename T, typename U> operator+( T&&, U&&)` etc which has [forwarding references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45996187/when-is-a-reference-a-forwarding-reference-and-when-is-it-an-rvalue-reference) and among all the four overloads, the last overloaded version `Obj2 operator+(auto&& x0, auto&& x1);` is the **best match** for the call `x0 + x1`.

---

For example, `Obj2 operator+(auto&& x0, auto&& x1)` is basically the same as(or **equivalent to writing**)

```
template<typename T, typename U>
Obj2 operator+(T&& x0, U&& x1)
```

This means that what you have actually is:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
Obj2 operator+(T const& x0, U const& x1);
template<typename T, typename U>
Obj2 operator+( const& x0, auto&& x1);
template<typename T, typename U>
Obj2 operator+(T&& x0, U const& x1);
template<typename T, typename U>
Obj2 operator+(T&& x0, U&& x1); //this is best match for x0 + x1
```

Comment: so I'm confusing forward references with rvalue reference?

Comment: @Saitama10000 Yes exactly. I think I should close this as dupe maybe.

Comment: yes, you can, but wait for me to accept the answer, 3 mins left :)

Comment: @Saitama10000 You're welcome :) Basically, the forwarding reference can accept arguments with any value category.

Comment: @Saitama10000 When you have `type &&`, if `type` is a template parameter or `auto` then instead of being an rvalue reference it is a forwarding reference.